# Router transformation in sql

Tags: sql, db2, informatica

I am working on a sql query which is complex. I have the idea in informatica but I am finding it hard to convert it to sql. I have a table which is a temp table created by various joins and unions.for that table which contains active student information I have to find major ids. Some of the students have only primary major id and they work in only a specific area other doesn't have a primary id but they could have multple secondary major ids. Major here means subject or course. In informatica I will use a router to separate the students with primary id and non primary Id in two groups and then for one's with primary Id do something and for non primary do something else. Plz excuse if there is any typo.

Comment: Can you show us more of your code or table structure

Comment: I would need a little time for that I am using smartphone right now but in couple of hours I will share what you asked. Sorry for that

Comment: i didn't quite understand what u want.. you can use CASE to check if he have a major id or secondary, or seperate it to 2 different selects, 1 for major and 1 for secondary and on each to do your thing..